# Mathtex and libpng kivy recipe

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I need this library to be compiled with kivy/buildozer: https://code.google.com/p/mathtex/

It depends on `freetype`, `numpy` and `libpng`.

Since I'm total newbie in bash scripting, can someone write `python-for-android` recipe for this?
Freetype and numpy recipes already exist, so, I guess, I need recipe for libpng and mathtex.

Thank you.

Comment: For reference, libpng is already included in the jni part of the build, though you might need to add a path to it to have it link correctly.

Comment: Can you show how? If I knew, I wouldn't ask a question. I'm trying, but can't understand how to make pieces together. In mathtex recipe I don't know how to include numpy.

Comment: Trying to write a recipe for mathtex. Freetype and libpng installed correctly, but numpy no. It somehows skips the process and when it is time to install imathtex, it says "install numpy first". How can I make it isntall numpy first?

Comment: Probably it just doesn't know about the numpy that is already installed. I'm not sure what to do to fix it, other than possibly adding a patch that removes this requirement from the setup.py (though more might be needed)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your own recipe using the this [link](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/#creating-your-own-recipe) and place it in the folder named recipe in the pythonforandroid. rename the recipe file as`__init__.py`.